# How to tell our asp.net core Web Api service how to serialize enum objects

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-core-2.0, asp.net-core-webapi

We are currently re-writing our API service that was written years ago. We are updating it using .Net Core 2.1 and MVC. There are a few kinks I am not able to figure out or find after searching. The biggest one is the enums that customers are sending in, are the enum description. For what ever reason the programmer(s) added a letter to each description (A,B,C,D... etc) so many clients are sending in the letters as their enums which worked. Now it does not work. We cant change the name because that also is being used. And I cant manually convert it (as far as I can see) because MVC takes care of serializing the object for our controller.

**Example**

```
public enum RentCode
{
    [Description("")]
    None = 0,

    [Description("A")]
    Buying = 1,

    [Description("B")]
    Renting= 2,

    [Description("C")]
    Own = 3,

    [Description("D")]
    Land = 4
}
```

How can I get it so MVC handles the number, enum value and description when serializing the object?

Comment: You really need to modify your question to properly describe your need.  After reading it and the comments in the answer below, this really has absolutely nothing to do with asp.net and everything to do with serialization (which doesn't care about what calls serialization, asp.net or console or winforms, it's irrelevant).

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion, I modified my question so hopefully it can better attract someone who is willing to answer my question. If I knew what the solution was i'm sure I could have better worded it, but because I am looking for the answer, I was not sure if the solution was different if I was .net47 or .net core. Or if there was something I could do on startup, or something built in to MVC to help. And if so knowing which version would change if I have a startup file or Global.asax file. So I'm glad to know those are not as important now.. a down vote later.

Comment: So asp.net-core uses JSON.Net to serialize objects.  The super easy way is just to use [EnumMember](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.runtime.serialization.enummemberattribute?view=netframework-4.7.2).

Answer (score 0):

I use an extension method to achieve this:

```
  public static class EnumExtensions
        {
public static string GetDisplayName(this Enum enu)
        {
            var attr = GetDisplayAttribute(enu);
            return attr != null ? attr.Name : enu.ToString();
        }

        public static string GetDescription(this Enum enu)
        {
            var attr = GetDisplayAttribute(enu);
            return attr != null ? attr.Description : enu.ToString();
        }

    private static DisplayAttribute GetDisplayAttribute(object value)
            {
                Type type = value.GetType();
                if (!type.IsEnum)
                {
                    throw new ArgumentException(string.Format("Type {0} is not an enum", type));
                }

                // Get the enum field.
                var field = type.GetField(value.ToString());
                return field == null ? null : field.GetCustomAttribute<DisplayAttribute>();
            }
        }
```

I call it like so:

```
//status is an instance of the enum
myObject.StatusLabel = status.GetDisplayName();
```

And my enum looks like this:

```
public enum Status
    {
    [Display(Name = "In Progress")]
            InProgress = 1,
            [Display(Name = "Complete")]
            Completed = 2
}
```

Comment: Right, we have these extension methods, but the object is being serialized for us, by the time it comes into the controller the enum is already null. We looked at the raw request to see what they are sending in.

Comment: is it JSON serialized? You can add attributes so newtonsoft knows how to serialize it.